# media queries for iphone image hide

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, css-transitions

i am using media queries to hide the image of desktop  and replace it with another image for iphone to reproduce better clarity in the iphone devices

but when i give display none its not making the image to hide

http://jsfiddle.net/Ww6PN/

providing my code below

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
          body {
          /*
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            */
            padding-top: 0px;
          }
          .da-dots{
            width: 308px;
          }
          .navbar-fixed-top,
          .navbar-fixed-bottom,
          .navbar-static-top {
            margin-right: -20px;
            margin-left: -20px;
          }
          .container-fluid {
            padding: 0;
          }
          .dl-horizontal dt {
            float: none;
            width: auto;
            clear: none;
            text-align: left;
          }
          .dl-horizontal dd {
            margin-left: 0;
          }
          .container {
            width: auto;

          }
          .marketing{
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            font-size: 12px;
          }
          .footer{
            font-size: 12px;

          }
          #iphoneSolutionContent{

            margin-left: 0px;
          }
          .desktopSliderImage{
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid red;
          }


        <div class="container">

                        <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider" style="">
                          <div class="da-slide" style="">
                            <h2>
                              <img class="desktopSliderImage" src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate1A.jpg" alt="desktopImage" />
                              <img class="iphoneSliderImage" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/banner1_iphone.jpg" alt="iphoneImage" />
                            </h2>
                            <div class="da-img">
                              <img class="desktopSliderImage" src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate2A.jpg" alt="desktopImage" />
                              <img class="iphoneSliderImage" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/banner2_iphone.jpg" alt="iphoneImage" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="da-slide" style="">
                            <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate2A.jpg" alt="image01" /></h2>
                            <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate2B.jpg" alt="image01" /></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="da-slide" style="">
                            <h2><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate3A.jpg" alt="image01" /></h2>
                            <div class="da-img"><img src="http://www.defie.co/docs/examples/frontpage_rotate3B.jpg" alt="image01" /></div>
                          </div>
                          <nav class="da-arrows" style="width: 100%">
                            <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                            <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
                          </nav>
                        </div>
                          </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: desktop? what do you mean by desktop?

Comment: @Chanckjh: the bigger screens for laptop and smaller screens for iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/6vFfy/

If you look at the first slide, if your window is above 767px it shows the desktop image (with the red border). For narrower screens it shows the iPhone image (with the blue border)

CSS

```
/* for window widths > 767px
show desktop image and hide iphone image */

img.desktopSliderImage{
border:solid red 1px;
}
img.iphoneSliderImage{
border:solid blue 1px;
display:none !important;
}

/* for window widths 767px and less
hide desktop image and show iphone image */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
img.desktopSliderImage{
border:solid red 1px;
display:none !important;
}

img.iphoneSliderImage{
border:solid blue 1px;
display:inherit !important;
}

}
```

Comment: thanks...will it not work without !important property and whats the use of display:inherit !important;

Comment: !important is required with these selectors. display:inherit is basically the opposite of display:none in this case, and it forces the iphoneSliderImage to be shown if the screen is narrow. FOr a definition see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp